# User not recognized by Express Passport with my strategy

Tags: angularjs, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have a strange behavior with my Angular - Express + Passport behavior.

On my application, a user is authenticated this way: the AngularJS application calls an external service, linked to NTML, which returns several information such as the email of the current user.
Then, the AngularJS application calls a REST service on my Express backend (`/rest/userProfile`) to get the full profile of the user. That's when I authenticate the user on the back-end.

However, at the same time, the AngularJS application (during its initialization) calls several others REST api on my back-end (such as retrieving the application configuration in `/rest/config`, some other stuffs to display on the homepage). These calls are not protected and are generally handled **before** the call to `/rest/userProfile`.

In others words, the Express session is created by the first request received on the back-end, which is generally `/rest/config` and not `/rest/userProfile` (I think this point is really important).

After all that initialization, the user can call some protected REST api, like `/rest/foo/`.
But it appears that *sometimes*, the user is then not recognized on the back-end, despite the fact that the request contains the Express cookie (`connect.sid`). The logs show that the request object does not contain the `passport` property.

If I refresh one or two times the browser, everything start to work correctly, i.e. the user is finally recognized. After that, during some times, I can restart my browser and it will work directly without problem.

It seems that if I delay all the requests (like `/rest/config`) to ensure that `/rest/userProfile` is the first request received on the server, everything works correctly (i.e. the user will be recognized correctly on protected routes).

- Is my understanding correct, in the sense that **with my current implementation** I have to make the call to `/rest/userProfile` be the first request received on the backend, so the session created by Passport will contains the user information?

  - If yes, what I have to change in my implementation (cf. below) to make it work, regardless when the call to `/rest/userProfile` is received (of course before any protected route)?
  - If no, what is wrong on my site? Any clue?

**The code**

On my `index.js`, I set the following Express middlewares:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxx',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

On my main route JS file:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('[serialize user]', user);
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
  console.log('[deserialize username]', username);
  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use('ntml-strategy', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'mail',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
  console.log('[ntml strategy]', username);
  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    } else if (user && user !== null) {
      return done(null, user);
    }
    // User does not exist in DB.
    // We should create a new user with data received from client.
    var newUser = new User({
      username: username,
      roles: ['user']
    });
    User.create(newUser, function(err, userSaved) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, userSaved);
    });
  });
}));

// The REST api to get user profile
app.post('/rest/userProfile', passport.authenticate('ntml-strategy'), getUserProfile);

function getUserProfile(req, res) {
  var user = req.user;
  console.log('[getUserProfile]', user);
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).end();
  }
  res.json({
    username: user.username,
    roles: user.roles
  });
}

// In other file, another route:
app.get('/rest/foo/', isAuthenticated, getUserStuff);

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(401).end();
  }
  next();
}

function getUserStuff(req, res, next) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

On the `User` model, I've set the `passport-local-mongoose`:

```
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
  usernameField: 'username',
  usernameUnique: true
});
```

Note that removing that plugin does not change anything in the behavior.

Thanks.

For versions: node 5.5, express 4.10.8, passport 0.3.2, passport-local 1.0.0 and Angular 1.5.